# MongooseIM mod_event_pusher RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, xmpp, mongoose-im

I trying to understand MongooseIM file configuration ( not easy , this is my point of view ) I spent 2 days to understand how I can config `mod_event_pusher` & `RabbitMQ` but not working
This is my config

```
[auth]
  methods = ["http"]
  password.format = "plain"
  sasl_mechanisms = ["plain"]

  [auth.http]

  [outgoing_pools.http.auth.connection]
    host = "https://---------------"

[outgoing_pools.rabbit.event_pusher.connection]
    amqp_host = "---------damqp.com"
    amqp_port = 1883
    amqp_username = "---------"
    amqp_password = "eld_8NZ_________DY8x"
```

But when I execute `./bin/mongooseimctl live` I have some error like

> Could not read the TOML configuration file

If someone have an example , it will be great .

Comment: The warning message should also list the line number - does it match any particular line in your config?
Moreover, https://esl.github.io/MongooseDocs/latest/migrations/5.0.0_5.1.0/ has some tips on the changes in the `auth` section - it might be what's causing trouble in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The provided configuration file is missing the `general` section. This section is mandatory because it contains the list of `hosts` that the server is handling and the `default_server_domain`, see the [documentation](https://esl.github.io/MongooseDocs/latest/configuration/general/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).